# Field access through array is slower for types with more fields

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, .net-4.5

The following short but complete example program

```
const long iterations = 1000000000;

T[] array = new T[1 << 20];
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array[i] = new T();
}

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    array[i % array.Length].Value0 = i;
}

Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}  {1}   {2:n0} iterations/s",
    typeof(T).Name, sw.Elapsed, iterations * 1000d / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

with `T` replaced by the following types

```
class SimpleClass                   struct SimpleStruct
{                                   {
    public int Value0;                  public int Value0;
}                                   }

class ComplexClass                  struct ComplexStruct
{                                   {
    public int Value0;                  public int Value0;
    public int Value1;                  public int Value1;
    public int Value2;                  public int Value2;
    public int Value3;                  public int Value3;
    public int Value4;                  public int Value4;
    public int Value5;                  public int Value5;
    public int Value6;                  public int Value6;
    public int Value7;                  public int Value7;
    public int Value8;                  public int Value8;
    public int Value9;                  public int Value9;
    public int Value10;                 public int Value10;
    public int Value11;                 public int Value11;
}                                   }
```

yields the following interesting results on my machine (Windows 7 .NET 4.5 32-bit)

```
SimpleClass      00:00:10.4471717   95,721,260 iterations/s
ComplexClass     00:00:37.8199150   26,441,736 iterations/s
SimpleStruct     00:00:12.3075100   81,254,571 iterations/s
ComplexStruct    00:00:32.6140182   30,661,679 iterations/s
```

*Question 1:* Why is `ComplexClass` so much slower than `SimpleClass`? The elapsed time seems to increase linearly with the number of fields in the class. Writing to the first field of a class with a lot of fields shouldn't be very different from writing to the first field of a class with only one field, no?

*Question 2:* Why is `ComplexStruct` slower than `SimpleStruct`? A look at the IL code shows that `i` is written directly to the array, not to a local instance of `ComplexStruct` that is then copied into the array. So there should be no overhead caused by copying more fields.

*Bonus question:* Why is `ComplexStruct` faster than `ComplexClass`?

---

*Edit:* Updated test results with a smaller array, `T[] array = new T[1 << 8];`:

```
SimpleClass      00:00:13.5091446   74,024,724 iterations/s
ComplexClass     00:00:13.2505217   75,471,698 iterations/s
SimpleStruct     00:00:14.8397693   67,389,986 iterations/s
ComplexStruct    00:00:13.4821834   74,172,971 iterations/s
```

So virtually no difference between `SimpleClass` and `ComplexClass`, and only a small difference between `SimpleStruct` and `ComplexStruct`. However, the performance significantly decreased for `SimpleClass` and `SimpleStruct`.

---

*Edit:* And now with `T[] array = new T[1 << 16];`:

```
SimpleClass      00:00:09.7477715  102,595,670 iterations/s
ComplexClass     00:00:10.1279081  98,745,927 iterations/s
SimpleStruct     00:00:12.1539631  82,284,210 iterations/s
ComplexStruct    00:00:10.5914174  94,419,790 iterations/s
```

The result for `1<<15` is like `1<<8`, and the result for `1<<17` is like `1<<20`.

Comment: I'm interested to hear someone with definitive knowledge answer. One thing I think will contribute to the complex versions being slower is the increased amount of data that must be moved from memory to CPU cache.

Comment: I agree with Carson63000 that the difference between the simple and complex structures is almost certainly caused by less cache advantage for the complex types. As for struct vs class, struct is a value type whereas class is a reference type so there's an extra indirection going on with classes.

Comment: Another interesting question is why is SimpleStruct NOT faster than SimpleClass? I would have expected that to be the fastest.

Comment: @hatchet: SimpleStruct  and SimpleClass are actually quite similar: load the address of the array element/the reference to the object, load `i` and store it in the field. Maybe loading the address is a bit slower.

Comment: @dtb - right, but as far as the cpu cache is concerned, with the struct, once a page of the array is in the cache, that's all that's needed. The ultimate data you're accessing is contiguous in memory, whereas with an array of objects, the objects could be scattered all over the heap.

Comment: @hatchet: Since all objects are instantiated back to back right after program start, I could imagine that they aren't that scattered at all.

Comment: @dtb - I think some of the time differences may have to do with interactions with heap layout. If you preceed the tests with `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` SimpleStruct beats SimpleClass instead of lagging it.

Comment: @hatchet: I reran the tests with the two calls added, but I get the same results as before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible answer to Question 1:

Your CPU reads memory into its cache a page at a time.

With the larger data type, you can fit fewer objects onto each cache page. Even though you're only writing one 32-bit value, you still need the page in CPU cache. With the smaller objects, you can get through more loops before you next need to read from main memory.

Answer (score 2):

I have no documentation to prove it, but I suppose that it could be a matter of locality. Being the complex classes wider in terms of memory, it'd take longer for the kernel to access distant areas of memory, on the heap or on the stack. To be objective, though, I have to say that the difference between your measures sounds really high for the problem to be the system's fault.

About the difference between classes and structures, I cannot document this either, but it may be because, for the same principle as before, the stack is cached more often than heap regions, leading to less cache misses.

Have you ran the program with active optimizations?

EDIT: I've made a small test on `ComplexStruct` and used the `StructLayoutAttribute` with `LayoutKind.Explicit` as the parameter, then added a `FieldOffsetAttribute` with 0 as a parameter to each field of the structure. The times were cut significantly, and I think they were approximately the same as the `SimpleStruct`'s ones. I ran it in Debug mode, debugger on, no optimizations. While the struct retained its fields, its size in memory was cut and so were the times.

Comment: I tested the Release build with no debugger attached.

Comment: Both structures are far too large to go on the stack.

Comment: @Trisped the stack is 1MB if I understand his code correctly the array is of size 2^20 which is how many bytes are in a MB. The array of `SimpleClass` objects is 4 times the size of the stack. It can't be stored on the stack. The structure is too large to go on the stack means you will get a stack overflow if you try to put it there.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - I think the reference to the array is on the stack (the local variable), and array itself is dynamically allocated off the heap (new T), not because of its size, but because of how it's created. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: @hatchet yes, I realize that. I was responding to Trisped's claim "the stack is memory, you can have as large of items in it as you want"

Comment: @Trisped Except there are no instances being placed on the stack and that's not what I'm referring to as the stack is completely irrelevant in this problem. Structure is obviously referring to the 'data structure', that array of 2^20 objects.

Comment: @Trisped it makes perfect sense you, just don't know what you're talking about. All data structures are objects and it is a very common term ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure ). On the other hand a `struct` is never referred to as a structure. If you google "Structure computer science" it returns the link I posted, none of the first page results take you to `struct` just stfu already please.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal As I pointed out, you do not use "Structure" in .NET as Structures are something specific http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289521.aspx.  A "data structure" is a specific concept in computer science, an industry concept if you will.  A "structure" is a generic term which, in this context, refers to a struct in C#.

Comment: If you used `[FieldOffset(0)]` on all the properties then you placed all properties in the same location.  In otherwords, there was no difference between `ComplexStruct` and `SimpleStruct` in your test case.

Comment: @Trisped Correct, but I assume (although I can't prove it) that the CLR still counts that number of fields in the struct. I did that mainly to identify if the problem was caused by the amount of fields or by the memory range they'd occupy.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1**: `ComplexClass` is slower then `SimpleClass` because the CPU's cache is a fixed size so fewer `ComplexClass` objects fit in the cache at a time.  Basically, you are seeing an increase because of the time required to fetch from memory.  This might be more clear (extream) if you go into the cache and reduce the speed of your RAM.

**Answer 2**: Same as Answer1.

**Bonus**: An array of structs is a continuous block of the structs, referenced only by the array pointer.  An array of classes is a continuous block of references to the class instances, referenced by the array pointer.  Since classes are created on the heap (basically where ever there is room) they are not in one continuous and ordered block.  While this is great for optimizing space, it is bad for CPU caching.  As a result, when iterating through an array (in order) there will be more CPU cache misses with a large array of pointers to large classes then there will be with an in order iteration of an array of structs.

**Why `SimpleStruct` is slower then `SimpleClass`**:  From what I understand there is an amount of overhead to structs (somewhere around 76 bites I have been told).  I am not sure what is is or why it is there, but I expect that if you were to run this same test using native code (C++ compiled) you would see that the `SimpleStruct` array performs better.  That is just a guess though.

---

Either way, this looks interesting.  I am going to try it out tonight.  I will post my results.  Is it possible to get your complete code?

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing more results on this. The code in the question is all I have, just duplicated 4 times for each of the types.

Comment: I ran the tests and also saw the same result of SimpleStruct a little slower than SimpleClass. I also got the memory allocated data from the garbage collector. SimpleStruct consumed 4 bytes per element, so there is no overhead with an array of struct. SimpleClass consumed 16 bytes per element (on a 64 bit system), which is probably 8 bytes for the reference in the array + 4 bytes for the int value in the object + 4 bytes for the object header.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your benchmark a little to remove the modulus, which is probably responsible for a large portion of the time consumed, and you seem to be comparing field access times, not int modulus arithmetic.

```
    const long iterations = 1000;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    //long sMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    ComplexStruct[] array = new ComplexStruct[1 << 20];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
        array[i] = new ComplexStruct();
    }
    //long eMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    //Console.WriteLine("memDiff=" + (eMem - sMem));
    //Console.WriteLine("mem/elem=" + ((eMem - sMem) / array.Length));
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int k = 0; k < iterations; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
            array[i].Value0 = i;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}  {1}   {2:n0} iterations/s",
        typeof(ComplexStruct).Name, sw.Elapsed, (iterations * array.Length) * 1000d / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

(replacing the type for each test). I get these results (in millions of inner loop assignments/sec):

```
SimpleClass 357.1
SimpleStruct 411.5
ComplexClass 132.9
ComplexStruct 159.1
```

These number are closer to what I would have expected as far as Class vs Struct versions. I think the slower times for the Complex versions are explained by CPU cache effect of larger objects/structs. Using the commented out memory measuring code shows that the struct versions consume less overall memory. I added the GC.Collect after I noticed that the memory measuring code affected the relative times of struct vs. class versions.

Comment: My code is a snippet of a larger program that I'm trying to optimize. The modulus is an essential part there. But thanks for trying this out -- it shows once more that locality is important.